# Is there a way to prevent Outlook from removing line breaks from emails?

Tags: jquery, outlook, mime-types, eml

When someone hits the "email" button on my web page, in jQuery, I put together some plain text and open it with:

```
document.location.href = "mailto:?subject=" + emailSubject + "&body=" + emailContent;
```

However, Outlook strips the email of all line breaks.
This issue has been covered extensively on Stack Overflow and elsewhere.

I need to create the email myself, and it will be other people who are reading it.  So changing settings in Outlook (to stop it from removing line breaks) doesn't help.

I have tried all the hacks given on the internet to trick Outlook into not removing line breaks.

Among them:

(1) put two spaces before the line 
(2) three spaces after the line 
(3) use "\r\n" 
(4) use two or more "\r\n"s: "\r\n\r\n" or "\r\r\n\n" or 
(5) add tabs before the newline or after the newline: "\r\n\t" and "\t\r\n."

The tabs are the only characters I can see getting printed, but I need line breaks.

I'm using Outlook Version 1708 (part of Office 365 Pro Plus).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, encodeURIComponent works:

```
document.location.href = "mailto:?subject=" + emailSubject + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent(emailContent);
```

I did not register the fact that `document.location.href`is a uri so of course it's going to strip out line breaks.

Comment: This was going to be my suggestion is that maybe it was not reading the `CRNL` combo.